# Treat file name as PHP GET

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have profiles on a test website setup to be viewed in this format:

```
example.com/profile.php?u=username
```

I would like to use this format:

```
example.com/profile/username
```

How would I treat the `username` as a variable in php, rather than a file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Create a file named `.htaccess` on the root of your website and add the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/profile/(.*)$ /profile.php?u=$1 [QSA,L]
```

now, if you navigate to :

```
example.com/profile/usertest
```

apache will send the variable `usertest` to `profile.php?u=usertest`

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I have mod_rewrite installed, allowoverride set to all, and tried both in .htaccess and the apache2.conf

Comment: Please define "__Doesn't work for me__" , also, add a log file to your `.htaccess`, i.e.: `RewriteLog "/path/to/log/somepath.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9` . Make sure the log is writable and  check it after trying again, what does it say?

Comment: `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` were removed. I changed `LogLevel` to `debug` and got http://pastebin.com/Z1k7nkhS in the error.log .

By "Doesn't work for me" I meant that the results are no different from if I did not have this rule; the server throws a 404.

Comment: Remove leading slash in `RewriteRule`. This is only mandatory when you're directly writing in `httpd.conf` or until Apache 2.4 i think. Here your rule will never match since there's no leading slash

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/profile/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile.php?u=%1 [L]
```

**or**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/profile/(.*)$ /profile.php?u=$1 [QSA,L]
```